# Compare 2nd column of the 1st file and 1st column of the 2nd file and print the matched records of the 1st file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have two files large files:

**f1.txt:**

```
5020118359      |13ZJ24001218                  |20141224|R
5020120475      |13ZJ38000813                  |20141204|R
5020127431      |13ZJ38001569                  |20141201|R
5020127689      |12ZJ44000606                  |20141203|R
5020127728      |13ZJ38001356                  |20141203|R
5020127956      |13ZJ62002544                  |20141205|R
5020127972      |13ZJ49000082                  |20141205|R
5020128325      |13ZJ57000785                  |20141210|R
5020128706      |13ZJ38002805                  |20141211|R
5020129084      |10XJ70107764                  |20141217|R
5020129102      |12ZJ54000041                  |20141217|R
```

**f2.txt:**

```
09Y903010552
12ZJ54000041
11XJ62118385
08Y909018946
09Y902011954
11XJ57120346
10XJ70107764
11XJ40165329
09XJ42008336
08Y912021435
11XJ51040272
07Y910027235
```

**Output:**

```
5020129084      |10XJ70107764                  |20141217|R
5020129102      |12ZJ54000041                  |20141217|R
```

it will compare 2nd column of the first file and 1st column of the second file and then print the matched records of the 1st file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `awk`? That could easily be implemented in `awk`. Here's a different solution:

```
egrep $(tr '\n' '|' < f2.txt | sed 's/|$//') f1.txt
```

`tr` is used to replace all newline characters with `|`, `sed` is used to remove the trailing `|` (I bet there is a more elegant way to do that, without invoking another subprocess), and then this is used as argument for `egrep` = `grep -e`.

Answer (score 0):

In the simple example you show, you can use `grep`, giving it `f2` as the list of patterns to search for (`-f`):

```
$ grep -wf f2.txt f1.txt 
5020129084      |10XJ70107764                  |20141217|R
5020129102      |12ZJ54000041                  |20141217|R
```

The `-w` makes `grep` only look for "whole word" matches, so that `foobar` is not considered a match for `foo`.

For more complex cases where, for example, `f2.txt` can have multiple columns or where the data in `f2.txt` could appear in any column of `f1.txt` but you only want those cases where it appears on column 1, you can use `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'[ |]+' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next}($2 in a )' f2.txt f1.txt 
5020129084      |10XJ70107764                  |20141217|R
5020129102      |12ZJ54000041                  |20141217|R
```

The `-F` sets the field separator to one or more `|` or space. `NR` is the current line number and `FNR` is the current file's line number. When multiple files are given as input, the two will be equal only while the first file is being read. Therefore, the `a[$1]++; next` will be run for each line of the first file. Since the first file is `f2.txt`, that will save each of the 1st fields of `f2.txt` in the array `a`. The `next` skips to the next line.

Then, when we reach the next file, if its 2nd field is in the array, then the assertion (`$2 in a)` will be true and `awk` will print the line. This is the default action for when an assertion evaluates to true. It is just a shortened version of:

```
awk -F'[ |]+' '{
                 if(NR==FNR){ 
                    a[$1]++; 
                 }
                 else if($2 in a ){
                    print
                 }
                }' f2.txt f1.txt
```